# Distributing amounts based on grouped running totals

Tags: powerquery

I am still a newbie in Power Query and can't figure out how to solve:

I have "Invoices" table (A:B) and a "Bank payments" table (F:I). I am trying to populate the paid amounts against every invoice row in C column, but the problem is that sometimes I have multiple lines for one invoice while the payment is a total amount. So when I simply merge them, I get incorrect figures:

[image]

In column C I get the full amount paid. I want to distribute it across the rows of the corresponding invoice and in case of a discrepancy, it to be added at one of the rows. As in column M.
I tried grouped running totals ideas, but as I still don't fully understand the steps in them, I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work

Load in and save the Bank Payments table as **bank payments**

Load in the Invoices

Add column .. .index column .. from 0

Add column .. custom column named **MaxIndex** that finds the maximum index for each invoice so we can locate the last row

```
//Maximum invoice #
= (i)=>List.Max(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Invoice]=i[Invoice])[Index])
```

Add column .. custom column named **Cum** that is the running total of Invoice Amount for that invoice number

```
// cumulative sum
= (i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Invoice]=i[Invoice] and [Index]<=i[Index] )[Invoice Amount])
```

Merge in the **bank payments** table, match on invoice, use left outer join, expand the Paid Amount and Difference columns

Add column .. custom column **Paid Amount** that puts it all together.  If this invoice is the last one (based on max index) then take **paid amount** - **cumulative invoice amount** + **current invoice amount**  otherwise just the **invoice amount**

```
= if [Index]=[MaxIndex] then [bank payments.Paid amount]-[Cum]+[Invoice Amount] else [Invoice Amount]
```

Add column .. custom column **Difference** that inserts the difference if this is the last row (index = MaxIndex)

```
= if [Index]=[MaxIndex] then [bank payments.Difference] else null
```

Full sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="invoices"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index","MaxIndex",(i)=>List.Max(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Invoice]=i[Invoice])[Index]), type number ),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom" ,"Cum",(i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Invoice]=i[Invoice] and [Index]<=i[Index] )[Invoice Amount]), type number ),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom2",{"Invoice"},#"bank payments",{"Invoice"},"bank payments",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded bank payments" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "bank payments", {"Paid amount", "Difference"}, {"bank payments.Paid amount", "bank payments.Difference"}),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded bank payments", "Paid Amount", each if [Index]=[MaxIndex] then [bank payments.Paid amount]-[Cum]+[Invoice Amount] else [Invoice Amount]),
#"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Difference", each if [Index]=[MaxIndex] then [bank payments.Difference] else null),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom4",{"Index", "MaxIndex", "Cum", "bank payments.Paid amount", "bank payments.Difference"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```